# Can't trim() Char(195) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ascii

I imported and am in the process of cleaning some data exported from an older Mainframe and have quite a few lines that start with an abnormal character (i.e. ASCII characters 194, 195, 226, etc). I can trim off most of the characters with a simple `remainder = trim(leading '%' from remainder)` (where '%' represents the character in question.

The only character that won't be removed is the 'Í'. If I run a `remainder = trim(leading 'Í' from remainder)` query it won't find and trim the character, if I run a `ascii(remainder)` query over my data it shows up as a character 195 for the strings that start with that character.

Next I ran a `remainder = trim(leading CHAR(195) from remainder)` query and that skipped the character as well.

Why am I able to remove everything else but this one character when clearly MySQL can convert it to it's ASCII character code and doesn't have any issues displaying the character when a normal select query is run and the applicable records displayed?

**Update**
I have also run the following queries:

```
remainder = trim(leading convert('Í' using ASCII) from remainder)

remainder = trim(leading convert('Í' using UTF8) from remainder)

remainder = trim(leading convert(Char(195) using ASCII) from remainder)
```

Comment: make sure you're using the SAME charset all over. you're probably corrupting the char with a charset mismatch somewhere, and it's coming out as a completely different char once mysql starts executing the query.

Comment: @MarcB how would I check this? Like I mentioned above, i did the convert to ASCII successfully and it shows up consistently in every other query I've run. Wouldn't I encounter an error in one of those if it was an invalid character? Is there anyway I can "force" it to convert?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: @MarcB funny you should mention that, I actually had run those queries (see my update above). Maybe I'm not using them in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works correctly on my MySQL ( 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 ).

Possibly the reason it doesn't work for you is that, due to character set mismatch, what you *see* as a character 195 **is not a character 195 at all**; it might be for example a 0xCD hex, or an UTF8 sequence corresponding to 0xC38D hex, in which case trimming the 'Í' would apparently transform it in something even weirder.

Try using HEX() to check the character in question. What is it?

```
CD     Latin1 Í
C38D   UTF8   Í      <---
C3     CHAR(195)
```

Notice that the Í is **not** a CHAR(195) at all, but 195 *is* the *beginning* of a Í in UTF8.

In a pinch, you can perform the operation... in hex.

```
select unhex(trim(leading 'C38D' from HEX('Íturalde')));
+---------------------------------------------------+
| unhex(trim(leading 'C38D' from HEX('Íturalde')))  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| turalde                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

This will *only* ever trim a leading C38D, or UTF8 Í, while ignoring everything else.

**UPDATE**: you may want to dump your table to a text file and try running `recode`, `iconv` or `fixcode` on it.

Comment: And we have a winner! @Iserni, that's what I was looking for and it works perfectly. Like you said it's not something that one should use regularly but when you get a dump of data from an older system, something like this is invaluable!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found *a method*. Using

```
remainder = trim(leading Char(195) from convert(remainder using ASCII))
```

I was able to finally get rid of that pesky 'Í'. My only concern is that it really didn't trim anyway, it turned **ALL** of the ASCII characters over 127 that would normally fall into the 'Extended ASCII' code list into '?' which could then be removed with `remainder = trim(leading '?' from remainder)`. It works for my current task but I am interested in more exact queries that can remove a specific character should I need to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What `CHARSET` do you use for your table?

There is no problem with `TRIM` function if you are sure that you have ASCII data in your table and character code is correct.

So just figure out your datatable or even column CHARSET before quering.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cfe9/5

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING CHAR(195) FROM field1)
, field1
from t1
```

Comment: UF8 - default collation, the 'remainder' column that the values are being stored in is a VARCHAR(4000). As mentioned above, i noticed that when i convert the entire string to ASCII it removes all of the extended ASCII characters and turns them into "?". Is there anyway to preserve those?

Comment: if you have UTF8 charset. you don't need to convert anything. On what stage do you get your `?` ?